# IHostBufferPolicySelector based on custom attribute

Tags: c#, stream, asp.net-web-api, buffer

I am trying to implement `IHostBufferPolicySelector` (C# and Web API) based on a custom attribute. I.e. I want to determine whether a request should be buffered or not based on an attribute at the controller's method. Like this:

```
[NoBuffer]
[HttpPost]
public void UploadData()
{
  // Read from the stream here...
}
```

How do I achieve this? I need some way for my IHostBufferPolicySelector implementation to determine whether the NoBuffer attribute is present or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's safe to say that with the current architecture of Web API it's a no-go.

In fact, controller level is far too late in the stack to make decisions about buffering requests.

`IHostBufferPolicySelector` is a **global** service, ingrained as low into the stack as possible - into `HttpControllerHandler`, which is the heart of Web API (it's just an HTTP handler). So it's really not possible to have it applied to a specific request like you would like.

What Web API does on every request in an *internal* method inside `HttpControllerHandler` is this:

```
// Choose a buffered or bufferless input stream based on user's policy
    IHostBufferPolicySelector policySelector = _bufferPolicySelector.Value;
    bool isInputBuffered = policySelector == null ? true : policySelector.UseBufferedInputStream(httpContextBase);
    Stream inputStream = isInputBuffered
                            ? requestBase.InputStream
                            : httpContextBase.ApplicationInstance.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream();
```

where `_bufferPolicySelector` is a global configuration value; so it selects the buffer approach based on that global value.

I reckon you could log this on ASP.NET Web stack's Codeplex issue list as a proposed featured, but for now you have to use one global `IHostBufferPolicySelector` setting.

The way I imagine it *could* be implemented, is that the assembly would have to be scanned for the [NoBuffer] attributes at startup, and some static config would have to be created with a map of urls for which buffering should not happen. Then, at the lowest level, in the `HttpControllerHandler` this map would have to be compared against the incoming request url to determine the buffering policy.